# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (57, 1) for Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm having touble feeding label values to a Tensor in tensorflow. My batchSize is 3 times the number of classes that I have:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,457)],name='Train_data')# each input has a length of 457 
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,numberOFClasses],name='Labels')#
.........................................................................
for j in range(len(batch_xs[0])-1):# this is the input data which is fine 
    print(sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs[j],y_:np.reshape(batch_ys[j] ,(batchSize,1) )}))
```

the code is fine the data is also fine the only problem is the shape of the labels `Y_`  here is what I get

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (57, 1) for Tensor 'Labels:0', which has shape '(?, 19)'
```

and the `size of batch_ys[i] is 57`

The way I see it is I have a batch size if `57 = 3*19=3*number of classes.` 
so my y_ should have `57` labels in it ? any idea what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable *numberOFClasses* is set to 19, you should feed a tensor with shape **(57, 19)** instead of shape **(57, 1)**.

The **?** in the error message **(?, 19)** always refer to the batch size which can be arbitrary.

So the problem is not your batch size but the shape of your input.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying, but still don't get it ? If I have a 57 batch  ( 57 sample form the data ) I need 3*19class to label it ? right?

Comment: Yes you need one label per sample, so if you have 57 input samples in your batch, you need 57 labels.